# Content property is set more than once

Tags: xaml

I'm trying to add a title to my xaml page, in the small space above the 4x4 grid, but when i try to add the label, it says content is set more than once.

here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationAssignmentgood.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid Name="mainGrid" Margin="0,56,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
    <Label Content="Hello" HorizontalAlignment="Center", VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial Black" FontSize="24" />

</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Window` can only contain **one** child. In your case, your `Window` contains a `Grid`, and a `Label`.

Ensure that your `Window` only has one child, you can achieve this by placing your `Label` inside a `Grid`. Something like this:

```
<Window ... >
    <Grid>
        <Grid ...>
            ...
        </Grid>

        <Label Content="Hello" ... />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```